# Chained view displaced in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I've encountered a problem with ConstraintLayout while simply placing 2 views in the center of screen. Like Title and Content bellow. Both should be centered vertically. So my layout looks like:

```xml
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android=“http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
   xmlns:app=“http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto”
   xmlns:tools=“http://schemas.android.com/tools”
   android:layout_width=“match_parent”
   android:layout_height=“match_parent”>

   <TextView
       android:id=“@+id/title”
       android:layout_width=“0dp”
       android:layout_height=“wrap_content”
       android:text=“Title”
       android:textAppearance=“@style/Title1"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf=“@id/content”
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf=“parent”
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf=“parent”
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf=“parent”
       app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle=“packed” />

   <EditText
       android:id=“@+id/content”
       android:layout_width=“match_parent”
       android:layout_height=“wrap_content”
       android:inputType=“text|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions”
       android:textAppearance=“@style/Title4"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf=“parent”
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf=“parent”
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf=“parent”
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf=“@id/title”
       tools:text=“body\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\nbody\n” />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But when Content growth Title is moved out of screen bounds. It looks like a bug. How can I avoid this behavior and make views to be inside screen bounds?
[image: Title view displaced]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `Views` that have `wrap_content` set for a dimension do not have their constraints enforced when the content gets too big to fit them. To change this behavior and limit the dimension you need to set `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` for your `EditText`.

As a side note, you should also avoid using `match_parent` for `Views` contained in `ConstraintLayout` as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout).

Comment: Amazing! You have opened my eyes on constraints. Thank you so much